# Better ways of saying "is able to"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, phrase-requests

I'm trying to complete my English coursework and cannot find a way around using 'is able to' in this context "Throughout the novel McEwan 'is able to' convey..." and I need to find another way of saying this.

Comment: *Succeeds in conveying* *Is successful in conveying* *Successfully gets across....* *Makes us understand* *Helps us to grasp...*

Comment: Consider dropping it entirely: "... McEwan *conveys* ...".

Comment: "McEwan ***ably/skillfully/adeptly*** conveys..."

Comment: Did he actually convey or was he simply able to convey? It's no joke the brevity is the soul of wit.

Comment: explains, teaches, imparts, shows, relates, educates, can ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try 'succeeds in conveying'. 
So the sentence will look like "Throughout the novel McEwan *succeeds in conveying*.......".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using "is capable of"? in your sentence it would be used as: "... McEwan is capable of conveying..." and should read identically after your passage.